# How to empty an item list in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays

I would like to know how to empty an element list in an array, to retrieve only the current element.
Let me explain, in a search form I use:

- an addObject function to add an id in an array.
- and a getObject function that retrieves this id.

The first time it works without problems and shows me the data I want. In my array I have, for example: [1]

But when I go back to the search form and start manipulating again, that's what's in my array: [1,2]

Here is my code:

my controller:

```
.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, appService) {
$scope.search = function () {
    appService.searchUser($scope.form).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $scope.list = response;
    });
};
$scope.showInfo = function(currObj){
    appService.addObject(currObj);
    console.log(currObj);
    $state.go('infoJeune');
}
})
.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, appService) {
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
    viewData.enableBack = true;
}); 
$scope.info = appService.getObject();
console.log($scope.info);
appService.userinfo($scope.info).then(function(response){   
    $scope.userinfo = response; 
    console.log($scope.userinfo);           
}); 
})
```

in my service :

```
var addObject = function(newObj) {
    element.push(newObj);
};
var getObject = function(){
    return element;
};
```

and my template :

```html
<form ng-controller="listCtrl" id="app-form5" class="list" ng-submit="search()">
  <label class="item item-input" id="app-search1" style="">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input placeholder="Nom d'un jeune" type="search" ng-model="form.pnom">
  </label>
  <a class="button button-positive  button-block" ng-click="search()">Search</a>
  <ion-list id="menu-list1">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="user in list track by $index" ng-click="showInfo(user.id)">{{ user.fname }}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

I will reply as soon as possible, and thank you for your answers :)

Comment: If you want the array to be empty before you push, then just initialize the array before your push statement

Comment: thank you, I understand now ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CrazyMac said you have to initialize the array

```
var addObject = function(newObj) {
    element = [];
    element.push(newObj);
}
```